# Ambiguous occurrence `Monad'

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass, ambiguous

I am currently working with Monad type classes, and here is my code:

```
class Monad m where  
    return :: a -> m a  

    (>>==) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b  

    (>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b  
    x >> y = x >>== \_ -> y  

    fail :: String -> m a  
    fail msg = error msg  


instance Monad Maybe where  
    return x = Just x  
    Nothing >>= f = Nothing  
    Just x >>= f  = f x  
    fail _ = Nothing 

main = do
    print $ return "WHAT" :: Maybe String 
    print $ Just 9 >>= \x -> return (x*10)  
    print $ Nothing >>= \x -> return (x*10)
```

and I got this error message:

```
Ambiguous occurrence `Monad'
It could refer to either `Main.Monad'....or `Prelude.Monad',....
```

I tried import Prelude and hiding Monad but get newer and newer error messages that are much more confused me, thank you in advance, Tamas

Comment: Give your class a different name (such as `MyMonad`) and change the name of all of its methods (like you did for `(>>==)`).

Comment: Your class kinda obviously conflicts with the standard one.

Comment: hello @duplode, thanks I change the names as you mentioned, like MyMonad, myreturn and >>== and the code is works, thanks you, Tamas

Comment: Why do you keep reimplementing things that are already defined?

Comment: @chepner, question is good, ergo I am a beginner, I like to reimplement things as a practice, so yes, probably easier to use the already defined things, but all of these activities are good learning points for me,